# Got 'GPG error' when try to fetch update

Tags: updates, error

OS version is 5.1.7 Hera. I got the following error when I try to update in app center:

```
- W: GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 793FEB8BB69735B2
- E: The repository 'http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release' is not signed.
- N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
- N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Since the problem seem to be vivaldi, I tried to remove it (I don't use it anyway) using `sudo apt purge vivaldi`, `sudo apt-get purge-vivaldi-stable`, and `dpkg -l | grep vivaldi`. After that I tried to update again, but the error persist.

I also tried to try to import all missing GPG keys using `y-ppa-manager`, but the error still persist.

I don't understand how to fix it, so any help will be appreciated. Sorry for the trouble and thank you.

Comment: Shorter:
wget -qO- https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the repo for your system:

`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list`

I hope this help you

Edit:

Could you please try:

`cd ~
wget https://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub`

Comment: I tried that, and the terminal said:
`rm: cannot remove '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list': No such file or directory`
And the 'failed to fecth updates' still persist.

Comment: I modified the answer, please try again. best regards.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it works! Thank you so much!